# Go - Windows to Linux

Tags: go

**Background:**
I am an absolute newbie when it comes to Golang. I am on 32-bit windows machine, downloaded `Go` compiler and wrote my first Hello world. Happy days!

**Question:** Can someone be kind enough to explain me the process of porting the aforementioned from 32 bit windows 64 bit Redhat.

Comment: Although go supports [cross-compilation](http://golangcookbook.com/chapters/running/cross-compiling/), I think it would be easier to keep RedHat VM for that.

Comment: @myaut Thank You. I will read that bit.